# Ubuntu 12.04 LTS install problem, stuck/crash at loading screen

Tags: 12.04, installation, dual-boot

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

Whenever I try to boot using the ISO from the website, it brings up the loading screen, where it promptly takes 3-5 minutes, and then either a) crashes to an artifact screen (blue/green pixels everywhere, light grey boxes) or b) crashes to a console screen wherein it brings up a bunch of gibberish of starting and stopping a bunch of processes (what I assumed to be what goes on behind the loading screen?). This has happened to me using both the 64-bit and 32-bit versions from Ubuntu's website. I also tried Wubi but it just got stuck at the loading screen for the 15 minutes I let it run.

This is all in an attempt to dual boot Windows 7 64-bit and Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. My laptop is an ASUS with a core i5 at 3GHz, nVidia 350m, 4GB ram, 500GB HDD.

Any help appreciated! Thanks folks!